# Почему не работает ToDo List на Сафари? (в частности тестил на Айфон 11)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Только начал познавать мир js, написал простенький ToDo list. Заметил что везде он работает корректно кроме Сафари на мобильных(не добавляет дела). Почему не работает на нем никак не пойму, есть знатоки кто может помочь? https://nogavadim.github.io/todo_list/

```
let today = new Date();
function gfg_Run() {
  let date = today.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
  let nDate = date.slice(8, 10) + '/'
    + date.slice(5, 7) + '/'
    + date.slice(0, 4);

  return nDate
}

// DOM

// Header
let container = document.createElement('div')
container.classList.add('container')


let header = document.createElement('div')
header.classList.add('header')

let headerContent = document.createElement('div')
headerContent.classList.add('header-content')

let title = document.createElement('h1')
title.classList.add('h1')
title.textContent = 'Список дел'

let headerSpan = document.createElement('span')
headerSpan.classList.add('header-span')
headerSpan.textContent = `Сегодня ${gfg_Run()}`


document.body.append(header)
header.append(container)
container.append(headerContent)
headerContent.append(title, headerSpan)

//main

let main = document.createElement('div')
main.classList.add('main')

let mainContainer = document.createElement('div')
mainContainer.classList.add('main-container')

let mainContent = document.createElement('div')
mainContent.classList.add('main-content')


let inpTask = document.createElement('input')
inpTask.type = 'text'
inpTask.placeholder = 'Введите дело'
inpTask.classList.add('inp-task')


let addTaskBtn = document.createElement('button')
addTaskBtn.textContent = 'Добавить дело'
addTaskBtn.classList.add('task-btn', 'btn-reset')


let list = document.createElement('ul')
list.classList.add('list-reset', 'list')



document.body.append(main)
main.append(mainContainer)
mainContainer.append(mainContent)
mainContent.append(inpTask, addTaskBtn)
mainContainer.append(list)

// переменные
let data = localStorage.getItem('ListArray')
let counter = 0
let ListArray = [];

if (data !== '' && data !== null) {
  ListArray = JSON.parse(data)
}

for (const msg of ListArray) {

  addTask(msg)
}

// Создаем id
function getNewID(arr) {
  let max = 0;
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item.id > max) max = item.id
  }
  return max + 1;
}

// Добавление дела
function addTask(obj) {
  counter++

  let listItem = document.createElement('li')
  listItem.classList.add('list-item')

  let listItemContent = document.createElement('div')
  listItemContent.classList.add('list-item-content')

  let numberTask = document.createElement('span')
  numberTask.classList.add('number-task')
  numberTask.textContent = `Дело № ${counter}: `


  let taskSpan = document.createElement('span')
  taskSpan.classList.add('task-span')
  taskSpan.textContent = obj.task

  let doneBtn = document.createElement('button')
  doneBtn.classList.add('btn-reset', 'done-btn')
  doneBtn.textContent = 'Готово'

  let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
  deleteBtn.classList.add('btn-reset', 'delete-btn')
  deleteBtn.textContent = 'Удалить'


  // кнопка готово
  if (obj.done === true) listItemContent.classList.add('list-item-content-done')

  doneBtn.onclick = function () {
    listItemContent.classList.toggle('list-item-content-done')

    for (const listItem of ListArray) {
      if (listItem.id == obj.id) listItem.done = !listItem.done
    }

    localStorage.setItem('ListArray', JSON.stringify(ListArray))
  }

  // кнопка удаления
  deleteBtn.onclick = function () {

    if (confirm('Хотите удалить дело?') === true) {
      listItem.remove()

      for (let i = 0; i < ListArray.length; i++) {
        if (ListArray[i].id == obj.id) ListArray.splice(i, 1)
      }

      localStorage.setItem('ListArray', JSON.stringify(ListArray))
    }
  }



  list.append(listItem)
  listItem.append(listItemContent)
  listItemContent.append(numberTask, taskSpan, doneBtn, deleteBtn)

  return list

}

// добавление дела


addTaskBtn.onclick = function () {



  let taskObj = {
    id: getNewID(ListArray),
    task: inpTask.value,
    done: false
  }

  ListArray.push(taskObj)

  localStorage.setItem('ListArray', JSON.stringify(ListArray))

  addTask(taskObj)
  inpTask.value = ''

}


// Неактивная кнопка
addTaskBtn.disabled = true

inpTask.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if (inpTask.value !== '') {
    addTaskBtn.disabled = false
  } else {
    addTaskBtn.disabled = true
  }
})
```

Comment: Скачайте брауезер сафари, поставитьте разрешение мобильника через косноль разработчика, поставьте точку останова и отладьте свой код......а вообще, скорее всего он что-то не поддерживает и в косноли можно будет увидеть.........